# Dog peeing only when I leave

Tags: dogs

I understand separation anxiety but my Havenese only pees on the floor when I am gone.  the area can be filled with other people but if I go missing or she can hear me in another room (even with others in her area) she pees on the floor.    I am getting exhausted that its only me and I can't ever leave her even with others.   With me she is 100% potty trained and night time crate trained.  I tried putting her in crate each time I leave area but she won't go into crate during day she throws up out of anger or anxiety.

Comment: Does she pee on the floor immediatly when you go or does she do that after a while? Does she have to see you all the time or is it ok if she plays with someone else when you go to another room? Would she stop playing? How do you react if she pees on the floor? Angry or understanding? Do you  comfort her when she does that?